# How to trigger event only in the element in use - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

**IMPORTANT**

Solved this problem by modifying my actual code. The simplified code below should work as expected, by my actual code wasn't working since it was made with functions and a different layout, but I now realized I made a silly logic mistake.

---

I tried to find this on google and haven't found and answer, I don't know if I'm not asking google properly, but what I want to achieve is something like this

**HTML:**

```
<div class="animates-whats-inside">
    <h1>This title will be animated when you put the cursor on my parent</h1>
</div>
<div class="animates-whats-inside">
    <h1>This title will be animated when you put the cursor on my parent</h1>
</div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$('.animates-whats-inside').on('mouseenter', function() {
    $(this).children().find('h1').animate(...);
});
```

**EDITED DETAILS:**

*I if I move the mouse inside the first div I want to move only the title inside the first div but not the one in the second div, and if I move the mouse inside the second div, move the title inside the second div but not the one inside the first*, right now it moves all the titles in the different sections. How can I achieve this? I'm sure this should be very simple, but I haven't been able to figure out how to search for this selector!

Thanks beforehand!

Comment: can you replicate this behavior in a jsfiddle/snippet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you dont need to do `children` since `h1` is direct decedent of

`.animate-whats-inside` . You can do like this

```
$('.animates-whats-inside').on('mouseenter', function() {
      $(this).find('h1').animate({
          opacity: 0.25,
          fontSize: "3em",
          height: "toggle"
        }, 5000)
      });
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/h2uugak1/)

Comment: OK this is it, what I realized, was that in my actual code I was not using the $(this) selector, that's why it just selected all the sections with that class instead of the one where the event was taking place! My silly mistake

Answer (score 1):

You could grab the first h1 and attach to it an event handler for the mouseenter event, like below  (I changed a bit your selector):

```
$('.animates-whats-inside > h1').first().on('mouseenter', function() {
    $(this).animate(...);
});
```

```js
$(function(){
    $('.animates-whats-inside > h1').first().on('mouseenter', function() {
        debugger;
        $(this).animate({ opacity: 0.25,
    left: "+=50",
    height: "toggle"});
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="animates-whats-inside">
    <h1>This title will be animated when you put the cursor on my parent</h1>
</div>
<div class="animates-whats-inside">
    <h1>This title will be animated when you put the cursor on my parent</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: OK this is it, what I realized, was that in my actual code I was not using the $(this) selector, that's why it just selected all the sections with that class instead of the one where the event was taking place! My silly mistake.

Comment: @JuanBonnett I am glad that I helped :)

Answer (score 1):

Yok can use hover event.

```
$('element').hover(hoverFunction,unhoverFunction);
```

Answer (score 0):

try to select the direct descendent of `.animates-whats-inside`

```
$('.animates-whats-inside').on('mouseenter', function() {
    $(this).find('> h1').animate(...);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

refer the following code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.animates-whats-inside').each(function() {
            $(this).on('mouseenter', function() {
                $(this).children().find('h1').css("color","red")
            });
        });
    });


</script>
```